# setTargetReturn in fPortfolio package

Tags: portfolio

## I have a three asset portfolio. I need to set the target return for my second asset

## whenever i try i get this error

asset.ts <- as.timeSeries(asset.ret)

spec <- portfolioSpec()

setSolver(spec) <- "solveRshortExact"

constraints <- c("Short")

setTargetReturn(Spec) = mean(colMeans(asset.ts[,2]))

efficientPortfolio(asset.ts, spec, constraints)
Error: is.numeric(targetReturn) is not TRUE

Title:
 MV Efficient Portfolio 
 Estimator:         covEstimator 
 Solver:            solveRquadprog 
 Optimize:          minRisk 
 Constraints:       Short

Portfolio Weights:
MSFT AAPL NORD 
   0    0    0

Covariance Risk Budgets:
MSFT AAPL NORD

Target Return and Risks:
 mean    mu   Cov Sigma  CVaR   VaR 
    0     0     0     0     0     0

Description:
 Sat Apr 19 15:03:24 2014 by user: Usuario

## i have tried and i have searched the web but i have no idea how to set the target return

## for a specific expected return of the data set. i could copy the mean of my second asset # but i think due to decimal it could affect the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error , when using 2 assets.
Appears to be a bug in the PortOpt methods.
When there's 2 assets, it runs : .mvSolveTwoAssets 
Which looks for the TargetReturn in the portfolioSpecs.

But as you know, targetReturn isn't always needed.

But in your code , you have 2 separate variables for spec.
'spec' , and 'Spec'

i.e.:  'Spec' .. assuming this is a typo, then this line needs to be changed.
setTargetReturn(Spec) = mean(colMeans(asset.ts[,2]))